# IIS app pool configuration and recycling for a website with multiple applications

Tags: iis, application-pool, recycle

My IIS website setup:

```
www.mycompany.com  <-Website
---app1
---app2
---app3
```

app1, app2 and app3 are applications - not IIS virtual directories.

There are four applications pools named sitepool, app1pool, app2pool and app3pool.

```
www.mycompany.com => sitepool
app1 => app1pool
app2 => app2pool
app3 => app3pool
```

Each app pool has its own recycle schedule.  My question is will recycling the sitepool will also recycle app1pool, app2pool and app3pool? There is nothing hosted under the website itself.  The website is just a container for the three asp.net apps.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely `Yes` it will `recycle all` of the website inside of your sitepool.

if your sitepool contains your 3 website.

```
sitepool //// if recycled the 3 or all of the containts of this are gone too.
-app1 => app1pool
-app2 => app2pool
-app3 => app3pool
```

Comment: So would you recommend setting up the recycle schedule just for the sitepool?  Ideally I would like them all to restart at different times but I am okay with restarting all at the same time.  

Do I need the sitepool at all as the website is just a container for the three applications?

Comment: yeah one site can contain more than one website or app. but you need to make it with different port.